# Imagem Button back to last activity

Tags: android

My project have 5 activities (1 menu, 3 sub menus and 1 help)

All activities have HELP Button (except HELP activity). inside Help activity have imagem button BACK.

What should I do so that when the help button is clicked it back to the previous activive?

I'm already using the method  to return the previous activity:

```
Override
     public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             Finish ();

         }
         return true;
     }
```

But beyond this I want to implement with the BACK button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Button buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXName); // The id of the back button.
// Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        finish()
    } 
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! Thank you!

Comment: De nada :) please dont forget to mark it as the correct answer and upvote :)